# How does importing work in swift?

Tags: swift

If i have a `function`, `struct`, `enum` or `class` in another file/nested folder

how do i import it to use in another file?
I'm a javascript dev and i've decided to pick up swift, so i'm still trying to wrap my head around this.

NOTE: I'm not building ios/macOS apps. I'm trying to build linux cli software.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you have nested folders in Sources. When using SPM, each level of new folder makes a new target. See https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#source-layouts I've never done it myself but I think in this case you have to declare these targets in the Package file, see https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#targets

Comment: so that means i have seperate my code into modules? i'd like to believe there's a better way to solve this. That approach isn't scalable.

Comment: Please post the text of your code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same target - you don't import anything, you should be able to use it without problems.

If you have separate targets (e.g. a Framework for a library) you should do `import ModuleName` to get access to the code.

By default things are `internal` which means you can access them in the whole module. You can't if they're `private` or `fileprivate`

Comment: That doesn't work, i've updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: What environment are you using?  From you screen shots it looks like the environment may not be aware that Main and Flag are supposed to be part of the same module.

Answer (score 0):

write "var main = Main()" any where you like to use it, then use main.getArgs
// by writing that you define instance of the struct

Comment: i don't understand you. please check the pictures again. it isn't the struct that's undefined, it's the enum.